# Cannot query using XPath when data element has attribute **xmlns="..."**

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have difficulty to query the value of a data element value, when attribute **xmlns="..."** in it and it's parents element. 
The following example is part of a SOAP response, and I want to get the value of first name and last name of it by using XPATH **/PartyInq_v2Response/PartyInq_v2Rs_Type/*[local-name()="person"]/firstName'** . But it return nothing. It can return value if I removed all 
**xmlns="..."** from the xml before query. Does anybody know how to query first name from the example directly?

```
<PartyInq_v2Response xmlns="urn:Somewhere.Int" xmlns:q2="http://SomewhereOps.v20120719" xmlns:q10="http://SomewhereTypes.v20120719.GenericTypes">
    <PartyInq_v2Rs_Type>
        <q2:person>
            <firstName xmlns="http://SomewhereTypes.v20120719.Types">somebody</firstName>
            <lastName xmlns="http://SomewhereTypes.v20120719.Types">nobody</lastName>           
        </q2:person>
    </PartyInq_v2Rs_Type>
</PartyInq_v2Response>
```

Thanks

Lu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what xslt processor you are using. But you have to make all used namespaces known to xlst.

The following xlst will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:s="urn:Somewhere.Int" 
            xmlns:q2="http://SomewhereOps.v20120719"
            xmlns:q10="http://SomewhereTypes.v20120719.GenericTypes"
            xmlns:t="http://SomewhereTypes.v20120719.Types">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:value-of select="/s:PartyInq_v2Response/s:PartyInq_v2Rs_Type/q2:person/t:firstName"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the namespace url is not known you can use local-name().

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xmlns:s="urn:Somewhere.Int" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:value-of select="/s:PartyInq_v2Response/*[local-name() = 'PartyInq_v2Rs_Type']/*[local-name() = 'person']/*[local-name()='firstName']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using XMLSpy for testing. Is there a way to ignore namespaces instead of define them in xlst? since we are using a tool to generate the SOAP schema, which will be used to create SOAP response message. Each time, when we recreated those schemas, the internal namespace (e.g. q10, q2) may different on each time during regenerating schemas, I.e. q10 changed to q20. which will be make it very hard to define (hard code) the namespace in my xslt.

Comment: Is only the prefix changed or also the url? If ony the prefix is changed this does not matter. If the url is changed you can use local-name as you already did. (See update.)

Comment: Thank you hr_117 :) But, as long as xmlns=blabla in the XML as attribute, the Local-name() is not working, at least in XMLSPy. That's why I post question here. If I remove those attribute, it doesn't matter there is prefix or not, it will work for sure. So maybe I should just use the first you showed me.